# How can i separate this div?

Tags: html, css

so, i'm making a twitch alert to streamlabs/obs, when a person subscribe at the channel, that alert will appears and show his nickname and a message, basically i want apply the background style just in the "this is a test" and let the nickname without the background color, but is one div for both.

how can i separate this div to apply differents styles in each one?

```
<!-- alert image -->
<div id="alert-image-wrap">
  <div id="alert-image">{img}</div>
</div>

<!-- main alert box window -->
<div id="alert-text-wrap">

  <!-- alert text -->
  <div id="alert-text">

    <!-- alert message -->
    <!-- messageTemplate will be replaced with your message template -->
    <!-- for example : {name} is now following! or {name} donated {amount} -->

    <div id="alert-message">{messageTemplate}</div>
    <div id="alert-user-message">{userMessage}</div>

  </div>

</div>


<!-- CSS -->
.widget-AlertBox {
    position: relative;
}
body,
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#wrap {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#alert-box {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
#alert-box.hidden,
.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}
#alert-text {
    padding: 20px;
}
#alert-message,
#alert-user-message{
        width: 475px;
    min-width: 48px;
    min-height: 4px;
    max-width: 475px;
    max-height: 158px;
    left: 234px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    top: 32px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#alert-user-message img {
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 1em;
}
#alert-image {
    position: relative;
}
#alert-image video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#alert-image {
    z-index: 6;
    position: relative;
}
#alert-text {
    z-index: 6;
    position: relative;
}
#alert-text-wrap {
    z-index: 6;
    position: relative;
}
```

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ydJO.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can target each ID separately in new rulesets after the one in which they are selected together.

```css
#alert-message,
#alert-user-message {
     width: 475px;
    min-width: 48px;
    min-height: 4px;
    max-width: 475px;
    max-height: 158px;
    left: 234px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    top: 32px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#alert-message {
   background-color: lightblue;
}

#alert-user-message {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="alert-message">Message One</div>
<div id="alert-user-message">Message Two</div>
```